# Unable to import git in python

Tags: python, windows, git, github

I am facing these issues. Can you help me with the same ?
Why am I seeing this error ? Do I have to add anything in the requirements.txt file ?

```
>>> import git
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
 import git
File "git\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
_init_externals()
File "git\__init__.py", line 23, in _init_externals
raise ImportError("'gitdb' could not be found in your PYTHONPATH")
ImportError: 'gitdb' could not be found in your PYTHONPATH

>>> from git import Repo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
from git import Repo
File "git\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
_init_externals()
File "git\__init__.py", line 23, in _init_externals
raise ImportError("'gitdb' could not be found in your PYTHONPATH")
ImportError: 'gitdb' could not be found in your PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 12):

I already had `gitdb` and `smmap` installed so I had to reinstall them.

You can reinstall them by running the following command in your terminal:

```
pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall gitdb; pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall smmap
```

Comment: This works! Thanks!
I have both smmap and gitdb installed already, and somehow both need to be installed again (same version). The command I used is: pip3 install --force gitdb smmap.

Answer (score 9):

I also got the message `ImportError: 'gitdb' could not be found in your PYTHONPATH` (when trying to use GitPython).
BUT I had gitdb already installed!
Thanks to [this hint](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/skulpt/QvxfPRLiVzE) I figured out that gitdb silently failed because it was missing [smmap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smmap).
So I installed this and it worked.

Comment: Upvote AGAIN.  Ran into this same error during a new Sphinx upgrade - and used this hint.  Thanks AGAIN!

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `gitdb` package.

```
$ sudo easy_install gitdb
```

Comment: I am using a windows machine

Comment: So you can use only `easy_install gitdb`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. However, gitdb and smmap were already installed by pip. As I used brew to install python and its dependencies on my mac, when I checked brew doctor command, it said that my /usr/local/sbin directory is not in my PATH. So I added it to my PATH (though it didn't have anything to do with the python) and everything worked out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

**MS Windows Versions** of this problem can occur **because of the order of Python versions in your system PATH**, as it did for me.  I did not realize that when I installed another program, it installed a newer version of Python for its own usage, and it appended my system PATH with the address to the newer version.  I noticed it when I looked at the PATH variable and found two versions of Python being called.  Windows uses the first it finds, and if the first doesn't match what your program expects, it gets confused and can't find the right path to the module.  This is what I did to resolve it:

---

**To check:** an easy way to test if this is your problem is to see if the paths separated by semicolons are in the right order.  That can be seen in the [System Variables of Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) or by printing your PATH variable in your CMD shell like in this example:

C:> **path**
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\**Python37-32**\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\**Python38**\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS

---

**Temporary solution:**
To see if it is going to fix your computer, change it in your CMD window.  Your variable change will be discarded when the window is closed.  One way to do this test is to copy the paths, move the Python references to the order they are needed, and write it back:

C:> **set path =** C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\**Python38**\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\**Python37-32**\Scripts\

Then run the Python program to see if this was your problem.  Note that this is only an example; do not copy & paste it.  Your path is customized for the programs on your computer.

---

**Permanent solution:** If the above test resolves your problem, you must [change your System Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) to make the change permanent.  For me that usually requires a reboot afterwards in order to make the variables appear in all new windows.